# Getting an index after shuffle() in PHP

Tags: php, shuffle

So I have an `$answers` `array` below.

```
$it = 1;
while($r = $query->fetch_assoc())
     {
         $answers = array($r['A1'],$r['A2'],$r['A3'],$r['A4']);
         $_SESSION['questions'][$it] = INDEX_VALUE;
         $it++;
     }
```

I would like to retrieve the value of `INDEX_VALUE`, but I don't know how.
The value of `INDEX_VALUE` is meant to be the placement of `$r['A4']` in the `$answers` `array`. For example, if `$r['A4']` is shuffled to second place, `INDEX_VALUE` would be 2.

Comment: I don't see any shuffling going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  <?
    $index = array_search($r['A4'],$answers);
  ?>
```

`$index` now contains position of `$r['A4']` in `$naswers`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it was so simple.

Comment: Just keep in mind that arrays are zero indexed, so for second place you would get 1.